# Python character encoding for '%C5%9' and similar

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

I am working in Python with strings, but I can't manage to display certain charatcers properly.

For example, I have this string:

```
%23%C5%9Een%C5%9EakrakTakiple%C5%9FelimYine
```

I have applied several functions to it to no avail. How could I display the appropiate characters in a web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two things.  First you need to unescape the urlencoded data with `urllib.unquote`, then you need to decode the bytes from whatever charset they're in, this looks like it's utf-8:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> foo = '%23%C5%9Een%C5%9EakrakTakiple%C5%9FelimYine'
>>> print urllib.unquote(foo).decode('utf-8')
#ŞenŞakrakTakipleşelimYine
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work when run from console. However, if I put it in a Flask controller, the decode('utf-8') function makes the my web app crash.

Comment: Crash?  is there an exception?

Comment: This is the error message I get: `UnicodeEncodeError
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)`